# Why is the kernel of an isomorphism always equal to the identity?

Tags: group-theory

I'm just learning about isomorphisms. Suppose $f:G\rightarrow G'$ is an isomorphism from the groups $G$ to $G'$. Why then is the kernal of $G$ equal to $\{e_G\}$? According to my source, we have $$\text{Ker}(f)=\{g\in G:f(g)=e_{G'}\},$$ and for an isomorphism we always have $$\text{Ker}(f)=\{e_G\}.$$ I know that an isomorphism is a bijection and get the idea of a bijection, but can't yet fathom how this relates to the associated kernel.

Comment: The kernel is a measure of non-injectivity. An isomorphism is injective, so its kernel is as small as possible, that means it's $\{e_G\}$, since $e_G$ always is in the kernel.

Comment: Note that the kernel is a property of $f$, not $G$.

Comment: Part of the definition of "bijection" is "one-one". Since the identity is always in the kernel, there's no room there for anything else in a one-one map.

Comment: @user18921 should I be speaking of $\text{Ker}(f)$ instead of $\text{Ker}(G)$ ?

Comment: @pbs, yes absolutely.

Comment: The kernel is not equal to $e_G$, it is equal to $\{e_G\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because an isomorphism is a bijection, every element of $G'$ has exactly one preimage; in particular there is exactly one preimage of $e_{G'}$. Since $e_G$ is already a preimage of $e_{G'}$, that is the one. The kernel consists of all preimages of $e_{G'}$, so is just $\{ e_G \}$.

Or, if you prefer the reasoning in symbols, $$g \in \text{Ker}(f) \iff f(g) = e_{G'} \iff f(g) = f(e_G) \iff g = e_G.$$ The last $\iff$ uses the assumption that $f$ is a bijection (actually, just that it is injective, as that is enough for the kernel to be trivial).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand, except for why is it we can assume that "...$e_G$ is already a preimage of $e_{G'}$" ? Is this to do with the structure preserving property $f(g\cdot h)=f(g)\cdot f(h)$, where the $\cdot$ in the left is multiplication in $G$ and the $\cdot$ in the right is multiplication in $G'$ ?

Comment: $f(e_G)=f(x\cdot x^{-1})=f(x)\ast f(x^{-1})=f(x)\ast {f(x)}^{-1}=e_{G'}$.
You can prove by exercise that $f(x^{-1})={f(x)}^{-1}$ if you don't know it.

Comment: @Galoisfan Thanks, that makes sense now :-)

Comment: Sorry, the statement in the last comment requires that $f(e_G)=e_{G'}$; in particular $f(e_G)=e_{G'}$ implies that $f(x^{-1})={f(x)}^{-1}$.

 A better proof should be the following:
$f(e_G)=f(e_G\cdot e_G)=f(e_G)\ast f(e_G)$, so by the right cancellation you have that $f(e_G)=e_{G'}$.

Answer (score 5):

The "size" of the kernel measures the "injectivity" of a function in the following sense:

**Proposition:** $f$ is injective if and only if ker$(f)=\{e\}$.

If ker$(f)=\{e\}$, from the equality  $f(x)=f(y)$, you have that $f(xy^{-1})=e'$  i.e. $xy^{-1}\in$ ker$(f)$. From the hypothesis,  $xy^{-1}=e$, so you can conclude that $x=y$.

Viceversa suppose that $f$ is injective; if $x\in$ ker$(f)$, $f(x)=e'=f(e)$ and  follows   $x=e$ thanks to the injectivity .